# Delete element from a list if it occurs in another list

Tags: python, list, loops

I posted my problem a little ago and i though i got the answer but still everything i saw didn't help...

So i have two lists and i want that if an element from list1 is present in element of list2 delete the element from list2 but till now i didn't find how to achieve this.

So for example i have those two lists :

```
lst_1=["A","B","C"]
lst_2 = ["123A","564Z","Beee","CD152"]
```

So i want to check if list_2 elements contains list_1 elements if so delete it !

So here for example i would like this output for a result_lst :

```
["564Z"]
```

I tried to do like this :

```
lst=["A","B","C"]

ma_var_lst = ["123A","564Z","Beee","CD152"]


for elem in ma_var_lst:
    for letter in lst:
        if letter in elem:
            print("element: "+elem)
            ma_var_lst.remove(elem)
print(ma_var_lst)
```

but it won't work as the index will move after deleting element....

If someone could help ! :) Thanks !

Comment: You should do something like: `new_list = [word for word in ma_var_list if any(c in word for c in lst)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and this works for me.

```
lst = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    ma_var_lst = ["123A", "564Z", "Beee", "CD152"]
    
    for letter in lst:
        for elem in ma_var_lst:
            for x in elem:
                if letter == x:
                    print(elem)
                    ma_var_lst.remove(elem)
                    break
    
    
    print(ma_var_lst)
```

Comment: for x in elem:
                if letter == x: can be replaced with if x in elem: so it can take more complex structures for elements in first list !

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with indexes too :

```
lst=["A","B","C"]
ma_var_lst = ["123A","564Z","Beee","CD152"]
indexes=[]

for elem in ma_var_lst:
    for letter in lst:
        if letter in elem:
            # get the index of the element
            index = ma_var_lst.index(elem)
            indexes.append(index)
            print("element: "+elem)
            #ma_var_lst.remove(elem)

for i in sorted(indexes, reverse=True):
    del ma_var_lst[i]
print(ma_var_lst)
```

Comment: Don't do things this way, you should just build *a new list*.